# How do I have a default null value if there's no argument given

Tags: php

I have this line of code wherein file_name has a value of `abcd223.jpg`

```php
      User::saveUser(request(),$file_name);
```

But there's also times that `$file_name`'s null since it doesn't have any values to get such as if the user didn't provide any avatar in the form.

What should I do in the `saveUser` method in the `User.php` file

Should it be like ?

```php
        public static function saveUser(Request $request, $file_name = null){
```

Comment: Yes, that's how you specify default values.

Comment: What problem are you having? Didn't it work when you tried it?

Comment: So this one's fine ? 

```php
 public static function saveUser(Request $request, $file_name = 'default_avatar.jpg'){
```

Comment: If you want that to be the defualt instead of `null`, sure. Why wouldn't it be fine?

Answer (score 0):

The default value only works if you don't pass that argument

```
function saveUser($file_name = 'default_avatar.jpg') {
}

saveUser();     # $file_name has a default value
saveUser(null); # $file_name is null
```

In your case, you may check the argument in the body

```
function saveUser($file_name) {
    if($file_name === null)
       $file_name = 'default_avatar.jpg'
}  

saveUser(null); # $file_name has a default value
```